# Xamarin Remote Desktop Connection App

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, rdp

I'm developing cross-platform (Android, iOs) Xamarin app which will provide remote desktop connection.

Are there any tools or libraries out there which will help me to get started?

I found [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/) but they don't have clear documentation.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: If VNC is an option and you are not tied to RDP, [this](https://cdot.senecacollege.ca/projects/vncsharp/) might be an option.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look.

Comment: @Taras I have a similar personal project, did you find any good vnc/rdp library for xamarin ?
Thanks !